# Twitter aouth API: Do I have to authenticate user every time?

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth

So after a user has logged in with his twitter account on my website, and I got the token and secret, when he moves to other page, do I have to generate the new token and secret in order to do something e.g. get his twitter username or I can just make a simple request to api.twitter.com/1/account/verify_credentials.json appending all the data I got on the page before, and it will work?

Answer (score 0):

When you got the token and secret of the user, you can make requests to twitter on behalf of that user.

So to use these token and secret for future use you should save it in some datastore along with the user's credentials. As long as you append these information to the request header you will able to make requests on behalf of twitter user without asking anymore permission from the user itself.

Reference: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/authorizing-request

Cheers